# Best solution for static member being accessed by instance reference

Tags: java, android, static, dialog

I have this method in nearly all my classes.

```
//listener - info
private void clickInfoListener(final ImageView iv, final int title, final int text){
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            materialHelper.showInfoDialog(MainActivity.this, iv, title, text);
        }
    });
}
```

Accessing this static method in a helper class

```
public static void showInfoDialog(Context context, final ImageView iv, final int title, final int text){
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_touched);
    //
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(text);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.gotIt, null);
    builder.show();
    //
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_primary);
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

I am getting lint warning of "static member being accessed by instance reference".  I don't know how to not use "this" here.  So I have two options.

1) Ignore the lint warning

2) Drop the "static" in my helper method.

Which is better?  Or propose a third solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The warning is saying that you're calling a static method `showInfoDialog` through an instance `materialHelper` instead of through the class `MaterialHelper` itself. This is "bad" because it suggests the method is actually an instance method that depends on some state in the instance.

The solution is to replace

```
materialHelper.showInfoDialog(...)
```

everywhere in your code with

```
MaterialHelper.showInfoDialog(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

> Or propose a third solution.

Replace `materialHelper` with the class name where `showInfoDialog()` resides. From your description, `materialHelper` is an instance of this class.

Answer (score 3):

E.g. , assume

```
    public static YourClass {
//.. the other code
    private void clickInfoListener(final ImageView iv, final int title, final int text){
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                materialHelper.showInfoDialog(MainActivity.this, iv, title, text);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showInfoDialog(Context context, final ImageView iv, final int title, final int text){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_touched);
        //
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(text);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.gotIt, null);
        builder.show();
        //
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_primary);
            }
        }, 25);
    }
    }


//somewhere
YourClass materialHelper = new YourClass();
```

So.

this method `showInfoDialog(MainActivity.this, iv, title, text);` is 'static method'

It means: this method is shared for all instances of this class (static variable too). It really doesn't matter where it was called. That's why lint says:
"oh gosh, why do you call this static method using this instance? It might change shared values in the other instances! Be careful!".
Java will understand your code but this is a small mistake (your misunderstooding). That's why the correct solution is to use this:

`YourClass.showInfoDialog(MainActivity.this, iv, title, text);`

Answer (score 2):

use with:

```
import static com.yourcompany.yourproject.materialHelper.showInfoDialog;
```